# Google Map fitBounds makes the map be in the ocean :)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this page where I have a listing of items per state.  If I try to do

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Then the map suddenly shifts to the ocean.  What I wanted it to do was to fit around the area of the markers.

Here is the test page for this:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/terrain.php?type=hills&geo=state&state_id=1

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize `bounds` at the end of `initializeTerrain` there are no markers on the map. Therefore it defaults to that spot in the Pacific when you later call `map.fitBounds(bounds)`. You need to extend the bounds after each of the markers are added.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 32.533470 , -87.786118 );
bound.extend(myLatlng);
```

...repeat for each marker.

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

that location is the center of the map, probably meaning that the location wasn't found. Maybe an incorrect syntax somewhere?